# How do I learn the process of application development by cloning an open source project from github?

Tags: django, git, github, version-control

I've completed a ton of django tutorials and now I want to get my hands dirty. Having cloned a simple django app from github, looking at complicated project layout and numerous files, it is overwhelming. However, I can see the (oldest first) commits from the author. Is there a way I can learn the growth of the project from oldest to newest commits? If so, what are the series of git commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could walk yourself through the project by rebasing it interactively:

```
$ git rebase -i <sha of the first commit>
```

This will open an editor (by default - [vi](/questions/tagged/vi)) with all the project's commits and an instruction of what git should do with them. The default is, of course, `pick`. You could change all the `pick`s to `edit`s (in vi: `:%s/^pick/edit/`), save, and quit the editor (in vi: `:wq`).

Now, git will rebase the entire project, one commit at a time, and return control to you after it applies each commit. So each commit, you'll get the prompt back, and would be able to read the current state of the code, deploy it, debug it, etc. When you're satisfied you understand the current commit, just use `git rebase --continue` to move on to the next one.

Comment: Hi Mureinik, thanks for the quick response :) the <sha of the first commit> will be the one that shows up to th end of git log command, am i correct?

Comment: @abhidoeslinux yes indeed.

Comment: When I enter git rebase --continue, I go to the next commit successfully. Is there a way to see which files are modified in that commit?

Comment: git log and git diff.  Try typing git --help

Comment: @abhidoeslinux `git show` will show the last change performed (from your current state). `git log -p` will show a log of changes, with their contents.